# SQL: Reverse six months moving sum calculation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got a table in sql which contains survey data for telcom companies. Sample data looks like as follow:

```
Period    ID    Q6_1    Q9_1  Q9_2   Weight   CompanyName
202212    1     110     h     i      0.348    Slimshort
202212    477   110     h     h      0.54     Slimshort
202212    474   110     i     a      0.65     One Dash
202212    654   110     k     i      0.32     One Dash
202301    653   110     j     g      0.44     Slimshort
202301    650   110     h     k      0.25     One Dash
202301    660   110     f     f      0.10     One Dash
202301    666   110     i     g      2.56     One Dash
202302    689   110     k     k      2.65     One Dash
202302    690   110     b     a      0.34     Slimshort
202303    710   110     i     i      1.34     One Dash
202303    708   110     f     g      0.54     SlimShort
202303    711   110     k     k      0.76     Slimshort
202304    811   110     f     g      0.54     SlimShort
202304    801   110     i     g      2.56     One Dash
202305    805   110     k     i      0.32     One Dash
202305    808   110     i     i      1.34     One Dash
202305    750   110     h     i      0.348    Slimshort
202305    760   110     b     a      0.34     Slimshort
202306    777   110     i     a      0.65     One Dash
202306    790   110     b     a      0.34     Slimshort
202307    989   110     i     g      2.56     One Dash
202307    999   110     k     k      1.76     Slimshort
202307    965   110     i     i      2.34     One Dash
202307    950   110     j     k      2.76     Slimshort
202308    888   110     h     i      0.348    Slimshort
202308    909   110     h     h      0.54     Slimshort
202308    911   110     i     g      3.56     One Dash
202308    956   110     h     i      1.348    Slimshort
202308    963   110     i     g      1.56     One Dash
```

Period column contains the year and month value when survey was conducted in format YYYYMM. The data is from December 2022 to August 2023. I want to create a view that calculates column based on moving six month sum of weight column for each CompanyName. I want to calculate the reverse six month moving sum of weight column. For example, instead of starting from December 2022, it should pick the latest Period column value (i.e. 202308) and select six month backward from there (i.e. March 2023 to August 2023, then second six months window should be Feb 2023 to July 2023, then third six months window would be Jan 2023 to June 2023 and last one should be from Dec 2022 to May 2023).
The desired output should look like as follow:

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
CompanyName    PeriodEnding     calculated_column1  calculated_column2   calculated_column3    
Slimshort      202308         
One Dash       202308
Slimshort      202307         
One Dash       202307
Slimshort      202306         
One Dash       202306
Slimshort      202305         
One Dash       202305
```

`PeriodEnding` is the column that captures the last month and year of the six months window. For example, if `PeriodEnding` value is 202305, it means the last month of six months window is May 2023 and six months window is between December 2022 to May 2023.

**Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Temp_view AS

WITH PeriodWindows AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        LEAD(Period, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyNameM ORDER BY Period DESC) AS PeriodEnding
    FROM RSQ_RESIDENTIAL_YM_V
    WHERE TO_DATE(Period || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') >= DATEADD('month', -5, TO_DATE((SELECT MAX(Period) FROM RSQ_RESIDENTIAL_YM_V) || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'))
)

SELECT
    CompanyName,
    PeriodEnding,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q9_2 IN ('h', 'i', 'j', 'k') THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) as calculated_column1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q9_2 NOT IN ('l') AND Q9_2 IS NOT NULL THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) as calculated_column2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q9_2 IN ('h', 'i', 'j', 'k') THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) /
    NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN Q9_2 NOT IN ('l') AND Q9_2 IS NOT NULL THEN Weight ELSE 0 END), 0) AS calculated_column3
FROM
    PeriodWindows pw
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(Q6_1, 2, 1) = '1' 
           
GROUP BY
    pw.CompanyName, pw.PeriodEnding;
```

The problem with my code is that it keep calculating six months moving sum of weight column for PeriodEnding 202304, 202303, 202302, 202301, and 202212. I dont have data before December 2022, so it means that calculation should not be done for PeiordEnding at 202304 or before because it requires six months worth of data from November 2022 to April 2023 which I dont have. The calculation should be stopped if there are not six months of data present. Any help would be appreciated to fix the issue.

Comment: this looks like a simple pivot, hav you tried it?

Comment: Is this actually sql-server? I seem some decidedly not-tsql code in there.

Comment: Are you sure `TO_DATE()` does not give you syntax error?

Comment: I've removed the incorrect tag, please add the correct tag for your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: The goal is to create a SQL view that calculates a moving six-month sum of the "Weight" column for each telecom company in a survey dataset. However, calculations should only occur when there are at least six months of data available to avoid incomplete results.

**Solution**:

You can achieve this by using SQL with a Common Table Expression (CTE) and a conditional approach.

The following code uses a CTE to define the periods and calculate the end period for each six-month window. It calculates the moving sums for the "Weight" column and other related columns but only when there are at least six months of data available. Otherwise, it sets the values to NULL to indicate insufficient data.

Here's the SQL code to create the desired view:

```sql
-- Create or replace a SQL view
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Telecom_Moving_Sum AS

-- Common Table Expression (CTE) to define periods and calculate moving sums
WITH PeriodWindows AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        -- Calculate the end period for each window
        LEAD(Period, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY Period DESC) AS PeriodEnding
    FROM YourSurveyData
    WHERE TO_DATE(Period || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') >= DATEADD('month', -5, TO_DATE((SELECT MAX(Period) FROM YourSurveyData) || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'))
)

SELECT
    CompanyName,
    PeriodEnding,
    -- Calculate the moving sum of Weight for each window
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) >= 6 THEN
            SUM(CASE WHEN Q9_2 IN ('h', 'i', 'j', 'k') THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY Period DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) as MovingSum_Weight,
            -- Calculate other related columns in a similar way
            SUM(CASE WHEN Q9_2 NOT IN ('l') AND Q9_2 IS NOT NULL THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY Period DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) as OtherColumn,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Q9_2 IN ('h', 'i', 'j', 'k') THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) /
            NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN Q9_2 NOT IN ('l') AND Q9_2 IS NOT NULL THEN Weight ELSE 0 END), 0) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY Period DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) AS AnotherColumn
        ELSE
            NULL  -- Set the values to NULL when there are not enough data points
    END
FROM
    PeriodWindows pw
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(Q6_1, 2, 1) = '1' 
           
GROUP BY
    pw.CompanyName, pw.PeriodEnding;
```